# Access another user's D-Bus session

Tags: unix, dbus

Let's assume this kind of situation: we have one user logged in, executing some application through `sudo` or `su`. This user has got a `dbus-daemon` running.
However, when an application running with root privileges tries to access D-Bus, it just spawns another `dbus-daemon`, owned by root user. That's not a desired situation.

**Is there a way to gain access to D-Bus session of user who ran the application through `sudo` or `su`?**

Comment: It should work if you do a `su -` from the user that holds the session to *root*, the other direction will not work, thats not wanted and would be a big security risk.

Comment: Indeed, and doesn't `dbus-monitor --system` help you in this case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you need `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` environment variable to be preserved when invoking application with `su` or `sudo`. Unfortunately, this is not enough, because DBus always checks (as a security measure) whether UIDs of the calling process and the session daemon are the same. The only workaround is to call `seteuid` from this application before connecting to the session bus. You can regain your privileges then with `seteuid(0)`.

Comment: Sorry for accepting your answer so late, I've had vacation. I didn't even need `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`, `seteuid` was enough (at least I was able to talk to Zeitgeist in context of invoking user). Thanks!

Comment: But if the situation is like this: We have 2 users logged in at the same time(A, B) Is it possible to connect to B's for example session manager from A?

Answer (score 11):

If you're on a systemd distro, the [relatively new](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/pull/1022) `machinectl shell` command can do the work of `su`/`sudo`, and it will also set session variables like `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` and `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS`. So for example, if I want to run `systemctl --user` as user `test`, the normal approach will fail:

```
$ sudo --user=test systemctl --user
Failed to connect to bus: No such file or directory
```

But this way works:

```
$ sudo machinectl shell --uid=test .host -- /usr/bin/systemctl --user
```

If you need to "reach back" into the user session that invoked a sudo script, you could use the `SUDO_USER`/`SUDO_UID` to hack something together.

Comment: `machinectl` seems to be gone now. I'm on debian testing. I think it was abandoned.

Comment: It's on ArchLinux.  This did indeed work for me, but I was trying it in a Lua script and it failed :(.

Comment: *buntu 19.10 contains a `/bin/machinectl` in package `systemd-container` which accepts this syntax: `machinectl shell otheruserlogin@ /full/path/to/command --arguments` and succeeds in reaching that user's DBUS.

Comment: The machinectl manpage recommends using `systemd-run` for scripting purposes. I've tried, and this seems to be the equivalent of your `machinectl shell` command above: `sudo systemd-run --quiet --pipe --wait --user --machine test@.host /usr/bin/systemctl --user`. Maybe that would be good to include in your answer? I considered editing it in, but that seemed impolite :-)

Comment: @Jack O'Connor can you please explain what is the ` .host` doing and why is this needed, if it even is ? Why is there a dot, why do we need to specify the host, etc... The manpage for `machinectl` indicates a classic `user@host` syntax and nowhere something like you did in your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure, and I've totally forgotten most of this. However, not that I try the command on my own machine, I notice that I need to keep `.host` but remove the `--` right after it. No idea whether that was a mistake in the original answer or something that's changed in the last 8 years...